# Bootstrap DataTable Sparkline Get data from comma separated string instead of array

Tags: javascript, datatable, bootstrap-5, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using a Bootstrap DataTable component and I'm able to get data from my db and showing it on my Asp.net Core MVC App. Now in a column I want to add a sparkline,the component requires the sparkline column to be an array of values but I have a comma separated string and I need help to understand how to change the JS in order to use my values type.

To make it more simple I created a new App without DB and using data defined directly in the JS as shown in this example:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/stocks.html

This works perfectly.

Now I have to change the value in "last" from:

```
  var stock_data = [
        {
            "name": "ACME Gadgets",
            "symbol": "AGDTS",
            "last": [2.57, 2.54, 2.54, 2.56, 2.57, 2.58, 2.59]
        },
.....
]
```

To:

```
  var stock_data = [
        {
            "name": "ACME Gadgets",
            "symbol": "AGDTS",
            "last": "2.57, 2.54, 2.54, 2.56, 2.57, 2.58, 2.59"
        },
.....
]
```

This is the js that needs to be changed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var stock_data = [
        {
            "name": "ACME Gadgets",
            "symbol": "AGDTS",
            "last": [2.57, 2.54, 2.54, 2.56, 2.57, 2.58, 2.59]
        },
        {
            "name": "Spry Media Productions",
            "symbol": "SPMP",
            "last": [1.12, 1.11, 1.08, 1.08, 1.09, 1.11, 1.08]
        },
        {
            "name": "Widget Emporium",
            "symbol": "WDEMP",
            "last": [3.40, 3.39, 3.46, 3.51, 3.50, 3.48, 3.49]
        },
        {
            "name": "Sole Goodman",
            "symbol": "SGMAN",
            "last": [16.20, 16.40, 16.36, 16.35, 16.61, 16.46, 16.19]
        },
        {
            "name": "Stanler Bits and Bobs",
            "symbol": "SBIBO",
            "last": [82.51, 83.47, 83.40, 83.68, 83.81, 83.29, 83.72]
        }
    ];

    let table = $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: function (dataSent, callback, settings) {
            let data = this.api().ajax.json();
            if (data == undefined) {
                data = stock_data;
            } else {
                data = data.data;
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i].last.push(data[i].last.shift())
                }
            }

            callback({ data: data });
        },
        paging: false,
        initComplete: function () {
            let api = this.api();
            setInterval(function () {
                api.ajax.reload();
            }, 5000);
        },
        drawCallback: function () {
            $('.sparkline')
                .map(function () {
                    return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
                })
                .sparkline('html', {
                    type: 'line',
                    width: '250px'
                })
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'name'
            },
            {
                data: 'symbol'
            },
            {
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return row.last[row.last.length - 1].toFixed(2);
                }
            },
            {
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    var val = (row.last[row.last.length - 1] - row.last[row.last.length - 2]).toFixed(2);
                    var colour = val < 0 ? 'red' : 'green'
                    return type === 'display' ?
                        '<span style="color:' + colour + '">' + val + '</span>' :
                        val;
                }
            },
            {
                data: 'last',
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return type === 'display' ?
                        '<span class="sparkline">' + data.toString() + '</span>' :
                        data;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

I tried to play around using some .split(", ") in the "data: 'last',render" but with no luck, also it is very difficult for me to debug the js (in site.js), I tried to put some console.log but nothing gets written in the output.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @andrewJames now my code is working fine and for some reason it doesn't even need any data trasformation, it's like automatically converting the csv string to the array needed.

I added also some other functionalities as grouping by a columns and transform datetime disply format with moment.js

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var groupColumn = 0;

    let table = $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        processing: true,
        ordering: true,
        scrollY: '50vh',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: false,
        searching: true,

        "ajax": {
            "url": "api/ApartmentsAvailables",
            "type": "GET",
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "dataType": "json",
        },
        columnDefs: [{ visible: false, targets: groupColumn },

        {
            targets: 7,
            render: DataTable.render.datetime('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00', 'MMMM D, YYYY', 'en'),
        },
        { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },

        ],
        order: [[groupColumn, 'asc']],
        
        drawCallback: function (settings) {
            $('.sparkline')
                .map(function () {
                    return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
                })
                .sparkline('html', {
                    type: 'line',
                    width: '250px'
                })

            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
            var last = null;

            api
                .column(groupColumn, { page: 'current' })
                .data()
                .each(function (group, i) {
                    if (last !== group) {
                        $(rows)
                            .eq(i)
                            .before('<tr class="group" style="background-color:DarkGray; text-align:center;font-weight: bold; color:white;"><td  colspan="8">' + group + '</td></tr>');

                        last = group;
                    }
                })
        },
        columns: [

            { "data": "building" },
            { "data": "floor_Plan" },
            { "data": "apt_Number" },
            { "data": "rent" },
            { "data": "bedrooms" },
            { "data": "bathrooms" },
            { "data": "sqft" },
            { "data": "available_Date" },
            {
                data: 'prices',
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {

                    return type === 'display' ?
                        '<span class="sparkline">' + data.toString() + '</span>' :
                        data;
                }
            },
        ]
    });
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
    // Order by the grouping
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr.group', function () {
        var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
        if (currentOrder[0] === groupColumn && currentOrder[1] === 'asc') {
            table.order([groupColumn, 'desc']).draw();
        } else {
            table.order([groupColumn, 'asc']).draw();
        }
    });
});
```

The only issue I'm facing now is that once I enable `responsive: true,` the sparkline column becomes hidden and when I click to expand the row to show the hidden columns it shows the whole array of Value and not the sparkline.

I guess that the

```
drawCallback: function (settings) {
            $('.sparkline')
                .map(function () {
                    return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
                })
                .sparkline('html', {
                    type: 'line',
                    width: '250px'
                })
```

is not able to be applied to column that is hidden.

Without the responsive option the html generated for the td is:

```
<td>
    <span class="sparkline">
        <canvas style="display: inline-block; width: 250px; height: 21px; vertical-align: top;"
                width="250"
                height="21"/>
    </span>
</td>
```

With the responsive set to true:

```
<td style="display: none;"
    class="dtr-hidden">
    <span class="sparkline">3446,3446,3416,3416,3416,3546,3546,3546,3546,3546,3546,3561,3556,3551,3396,3396,3396,3346,3306,3306,3306</span>
</td>
```

I presume that I should somehow capture the mouse click on the expand icon and then re-inject the canvas but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each string containing comma-separated numbers back to an array of numbers using this:

```js
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].last = data[i].last.split(",").map(element => {
        return Number(element);
    });
}
```

This performs a standard `split()` - but that gives you string values in the array. So we also use the `map()` function to convert each mumber-as-string back to a number.

Where to place this?

In your code in the question, it goes after this line:

```
data = stock_data;
```

---

Here is a self-contained demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stock_data = [
        {
            "name": "ACME Gadgets",
            "symbol": "AGDTS",
            "last": "2.57, 2.54, 2.54, 2.56, 2.57, 2.58, 2.59"
        },
        {
            "name": "Spry Media Productions",
            "symbol": "SPMP",
            "last": "1.12, 1.11, 1.08, 1.08, 1.09, 1.11, 1.08"
        },
        {
            "name": "Widget Emporium",
            "symbol": "WDEMP",
            "last": "3.40, 3.39, 3.46, 3.51, 3.50, 3.48, 3.49"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sole Goodman",
            "symbol": "SGMAN",
            "last": "16.20, 16.40, 16.36, 16.35, 16.61, 16.46, 16.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "Stanler Bits and Bobs",
            "symbol": "SBIBO",
            "last": "82.51, 83.47, 83.40, 83.68, 83.81, 83.29, 83.72"
        }
    ];
 
    let table = $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: function(dataSent, callback, settings) {
            let data = this.api().ajax.json();
            if(data == undefined) {
                data = stock_data;
                for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i].last = data[i].last.split(",").map(element => {
                        return Number(element);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                data = data.data;
                for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i].last.push(data[i].last.shift())
                }
            }

            callback({data: data});
        },
        paging: false,
        initComplete: function() {
            let api = this.api();
            setInterval(function() {
                api.ajax.reload();
            }, 5000);
        },
        drawCallback: function() {
            $('.sparkline')
                .map(function() {
                    return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
                })
                .sparkline('html', {
                    type: 'line',
                    width: '250px'
                })
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'name'
            },
            {
                data: 'symbol'
            },
            {
                data: null,
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return row.last[row.last.length - 1].toFixed(2);
                }
            },
            {
                data: null,
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    var val = (row.last[row.last.length - 1] - row.last[row.last.length - 2]).toFixed(2);
                    var colour = val < 0 ? 'red' : 'green'
                    return type === 'display' ?
                        '<span style="color:' + colour + '">' + val + '</span>' :
                        val;
                }
            },
            {
                data: 'last',
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return type === 'display' ?
                        '<span class="sparkline">' + data.toString() + '</span>' :
                        data;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>  
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sparklines/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Difference</th>
                <th>Last</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Difference</th>
                <th>Last</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Update**

Regarding the comment: If you are actually using the following as your real data source...

```
ajax: "api/ApartmentsAvailables"
```

...then you can adapt the same logic as above.

To do this you will need to expand your DataTables `ajax` option to use the DataTables `dataSrc` option. Using this option allows you to pre-process the JSON you receive from the Ajax URL - and convert those comma-separated strings back to arrays of numbers, using basically the same logic as I used above.

```js
"ajax": {
    "url": "api/ApartmentsAvailables",
    "dataSrc": function ( json ) { // the JSON containing strings

      // transform the received JSON here...
  
      return json;  // the updated JSON containing arrays
    }
}
```

You can `console.log( json )` if you need to double-check the exact structure of the JSON before and after you have transformed it.

I don't know the structure of the JSON you are receiving from your URL, so you may need to adjust my original code to fit your actual JSON. Give it a try and if you get stuck you can ask a new question - but there are  a lot of questions about `dataSrc` on Stack Overflow.

Here is the official documentation: [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc). As you can see from my example above, you need to look at the syntax and examples for the `function` syntax.

Comment: ok now that the example works, I need to apply the same to my "real" project.. the problem is that in the real project the ajax part is like this

`ajax: "api/ApartmentsAvailables",`

How can I apply a similar concept with this?

Comment: I added some notes - they should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you andrewJames! I'll try to take a look at it as soon as I get Home. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: So.. I don't know exactly why but I was starting to play with the `dataSrc` when I realized that it's not really needed. For some reason using `ajax: "api/ApartmentsAvailables"` would require some data transformation but using it like this:

`"ajax": {`
            `"url": "api/ApartmentsAvailables",`
            `"type": "GET",`
            `"contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",`
            `"dataType": "json",`
        `},`
 doesn't require any change..it seems to be converting the String to Array automatically.. it's just working as is :-)

Comment: I edited my original post with Updates and a new issue

Comment: If you have a new issue, you can create a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

```
stock_data[n].last.toSring();
```

n like the index of elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString

Comment: I’m not really sure how would I implement that in my code

Comment: maybe iterate the array and update the proerty last with the spread operator.. or create a copy like 

` let stock_data_update= stock_data.forEach(item=>return ...item, item.last: item.last.toString())`